# Is there a way to run NPM scripts in Google App Engine?

Tags: express, google-app-engine, knex.js

I have an Express API that I want to run on Google App Engine and it uses Knex.js for migrations. Can I run the `knex migrate:latest` in Google app engine? Or how would I work around that?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, Knex.js is an SQL query builder for Postgres, MSSQL, MySQL, MariaDB, SQLite3, Oracle, and Amazon Redshift.

Do you mean to migrate your database with Knex? Once you intend to migrate your API to App Engine, Cloud SQL will be a proper choice for your database. Knex still works to migrate databases to Cloud SQL, you can refer to this Stackoverflow case for the information about [migrate to Cloud SQL by Knex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47204845/running-knex-migrations-in-cloud-sql).

As your API runtime uses Express.js/Javascript, before you migrate to App Engine, you must consider first which environment is right for you. The standard environment is good for apps that experience sudden and extreme spikes of traffic (demands scaling) while Flex environment is suitable for apps frameworks that include native code (more control to your app and environment). You may refer to this [document](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/the-appengine-environments) for more information.

To be more specific, since your API is using Express.js, you just need to [add express into the package.json](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/specifying-dependencies#installing_a_web_framework) as shown below:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "lodash": "^4.0.1",
    "express": "^4.16.2"
  }
}
```

When you deploy your app, the Node.js runtime will automatically install all dependencies.

Comment: So I just add any npm scripts to the prestart script in package json.

Comment: yes, you just need to add express into the package.json as a dependency.